# picturebox.Refresh slows down program

Tags: vb.net

```
 g.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, 10 + p, 10 + p)
 g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, x, y, 10 + p, 10 + p)
 PictureBox1.Refresh()
```

I am using this code to draw in a picturebox. When i refresh it makes the program extremely slow. I have tried to invalidate() nothing works. It only works when refresh, but then it is so slow.
I am drawing 8 circles in the picturebox. When i use Picturebox.Update() it is much faster but only the first circle apears? Why would this be?

Comment: Which event are you using to do the above drawing code in?  Overriding the OnPaint event is usually a better way to go.

Comment: All drawing should be done on the `Paint` event of the control in question, either in the event handler or in an overridden `OnPaint` method.  Calling `Refresh` actually raises the `Paint` event, you're obviously doing something wrong.